# OpenLayers JSON based result with popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

I've made the code so that I get yellow points on my map, the coords and some other facts is loaded from a external file.

Here's the resource file

```
var sites = [{id:1269209,geometry:{ type:"Point",lat:1,lon: 1},properties:{siteName:"Yttern",parentId:1269209,siteType:2}}];
```

And here's the script for viewing them

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay");
$.getScript('test.js',function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++)
    {
        var site = sites[i];
        var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(site.geometry.lon,site.geometry.lat));
    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
}
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);

});
```

The thing I woundering about is how do I do to make a hoverable popup for each marker, with the content from the JSON file?
Is it also possible to make the request only when the user have passed zoom level 14?

---

Now, I've fixed the function that starts when zoom passed 10

```
map.events.register("moveend", null, function(){

      if(map.zoom >= 10)
      {
        var bounds = map.getExtent();
        var ne = new OpenLayers.LonLat(bounds.right,bounds.top).transform(map.getProjectionObject(),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
        var sw = new OpenLayers.LonLat(bounds.left,bounds.bottom).transform(map.getProjectionObject(),new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"));
        var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Layer");
        $.getScript('ajax.php?a=markers&type=javascript&sw=('+sw.lon+','+sw.lat+')&ne=('+ne.lon+','+ne.lat+')',function(){
        //$.getScript('test.js',function(){
            for(var i = 0; i < sites.length; i++)
            {
                var site = sites[i];
                var latlon = new OpenLayers.LonLat(site.geo.lon,site.geo.lat);
                var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                    new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(latlon)
                );
                vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
            }
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        });
        }
    });
```

but still I dont get the markers on the map, is something wrong? 
One result from markers.php aka ajax.php?a=markers....

```
var sites = [{siteId:'9',siteName:'Hårleby',geo:{lon:11.641452694427471,lat:58.15782686109065},fact:{parentSiteId:0,county:'Orust'}}];
```

is it the projection on the result maybe? Please help.